# How to stop gl from hanging after several (7) frames?

Tags: c, opengl, x11

Using OpenGL and X11, I have a program that updates an X11 window to create an animation, but the animation hangs after several frames. How do I fix this?

I have tried glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_ACCUM_BUFFER_BIT) and XClearWindow but to no avail.

The full code is here: https://github.com/alexrockhill/V1Model but here is the part of relevance to the issue:

```c
int plot_network(nw)
  struct network nw;
{
  Display               *dpy;
  Window                win;
  Bool                  doubleBuffer = True;
  XVisualInfo           *vi = NULL;
  Colormap              cmap;
  XSetWindowAttributes  swa;
  GLXContext            cx;
  XEvent                event;
  int                   screen_num, t_ind, ori_ind;
  unsigned int          display_width, display_height, size; 
  float                 delta;
  static Bool           displayListInited = False;

  if(!(dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL)))
    fatalError("could not open display");
  if(!(vi = glXChooseVisual(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy), dblBuf))) {
    if(!(vi = glXChooseVisual(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy), sngBuf)))
      fatalError("no RGB visual with depth buffer");
    doubleBuffer = False;
  }
  if(vi->class != TrueColor)
    fatalError("TrueColor visual required for this program");
  if(!(cx = glXCreateContext(dpy, vi, None, True)))
    fatalError("could not create rendering context");
  screen_num = DefaultScreen(dpy);
  display_width = DisplayWidth(dpy, screen_num);
  display_height = DisplayHeight(dpy, screen_num);
  if (display_width < display_height) {
    size = display_width*0.8;
  } else {
    size = display_height*0.8;
  }
  delta = 2.0/nw.dim;
  cmap = XCreateColormap(dpy,RootWindow(dpy,vi->screen),vi->visual,AllocNone);
  swa.colormap = cmap;
  swa.border_pixel = 0;
  swa.event_mask = ExposureMask | ButtonPressMask | StructureNotifyMask;
  win = XCreateWindow(dpy,RootWindow(dpy,vi->screen),0,0,size,size,
    0,vi->depth,InputOutput,vi->visual,
    CWBorderPixel | CWColormap | CWEventMask,
    &swa);
  XSetStandardProperties(dpy,win,"V1 Model","V1 Model",None,None,0,NULL);
  glXMakeCurrent(dpy, win, cx);
  XMapWindow(dpy, win);

  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glOrtho(0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);

  t_ind = 0;
  while(t_ind < nw.n_steps) {
    XNextEvent(dpy, &event);
    //XClearWindow(dpy, win);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_ACCUM_BUFFER_BIT);
    for(int i=0;i<nw.dim;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<nw.dim;j++){
            float v = 0;
            for (int k=0; k < nw.oris; k++) {
                v += nw.cols[i][j].ns[k].v[t_ind];
            }
            v /= (float) nw.oris;
            float x = nw.cols[i][j].ns[0].x*delta-1;
            float y = nw.cols[i][j].ns[0].y*delta-1;
            draw_box(red(v), green(v), blue(v), x, y, delta, delta);
        }
    }
    if(doubleBuffer)
      glXSwapBuffers(dpy, win); 
    else
      glFlush();
    printf("Time: %i\n", t_ind);
    usleep(500000);
    t_ind++;
  }
  XCloseDisplay(dpy);
  return(0);
}
```

I expect the animation to go on for n_steps number of time points >> 7 but it always hangs up after only a few (7) animation updates.

Comment: Unrelated note: Don't know where you got this example code from, but it's using some very archaic C style (like K&R style function signatures); I'd consider looking for more up-to-date examples. Also, if you just want to learn some OpenGL rather than `Xlib` it might be easier with a somewhat higher level library like `SDL2` or `GLFW`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably your use of `XNextEvent`; For one, if you produce events faster than you are rendering you won't clear your event queue. On the other hand, if you have no events in the event queue you'll hang in this function until you do.

Try

```
for(int i = 0; i < XEventsQueued(dpy, QueuedAlready); ++i) {
  XNextEvent(dpy, &event);
  // handle event here
}
```

instead. Disclaimer: Take with a grain of salt as I've never used `Xlib` directly in my life.

Comment: You're mostly correct, however submitting commands to an X server is no source of events, so OP is not producing events at all. Most likely those 7 events are from moving or resizing the window, moving the mouse, etc, that did queue up before rendering.

Comment: @datenwolf I meant 'you' as in 'the system this is running on', I didn't mean the application. I'm not sure how X works, but I was imagining things like the initial creation of the window and potentially mouse move and things like that creating events, so for example if the user was smashing their keyboard in frustration this might overwhelm the event queue (which I imagine has a maximum buffer size)

Comment: The X event queue doesn't "overflow" that quickly. For one, the events themselves are pretty small (only a few bytes) and for practical reasons the buffers on either end are at least a few kB in size (though the size isn't specified), and thereby can queue up literally thousands of events. What might be a problem is, if you don't process those events quickly. Like if you process only one event per redraw. Usually with each iteration of the event loop you want to fetch and coalesce all pending events before even dispatching to the event handlers.

Comment: @datenwolf That is what I said... the code in the question only processed one event per draw, and then put a pretty long wait in their loop as well. It won't take that long to get a couple thousand or even tens of thousands of events queued up if you only process one event every half a second.

Comment: Hey that worked, the simplest fix was just
```c
while (XPending(dpy)) {
  XNextEvent(dpy, &event);
}
```

Comment: @aprock `XPending` can block according to the documentation, so I'd not recommend it in this scenario. If you want a shorthand, use `XQLength` instead.